# How do I have to set up some scripts on windows?

Tags: windows, powershell, npm, cmd, cypress

I'm currently using Cypress, and I would like to run some commands. However, I'm pretty new to Windows, and I'm having issues setting up the script to do the right thing.

```
 "scripts": {
    "clean:reports": "rm -r -fo cypress\\reports && mkdir cypress\\reports && mkdir cypress\\reports\\mochareports",
    "pretest": "npm run clean:reports",
    "scripts": "cypress run",
    "combine-reports": "mochawesome-merge --reportDir cypress\\reports\\mocha > Cypress\\reports\\mochareports\\reports.json",
    "generate-reports": "merge Cypress\\reports\\mochareports\\report.json -f report -o Cypress\\reports\\mochareports",
    "posttest": "npm run combine-reports && npm run generate-report",
    "test": "npm run scripts || npm run posttest"
  }
```

Error message:

```
 Cypress_Mocha@1.0.0 pretest C:\Users\aharo\Desktop\Automation\Cypress_Mocha
> npm run clean:reports


> Cypress_Mocha@1.0.0 clean:reports C:\Users\aharo\Desktop\Automation\Cypress_Mocha
> rmdir .\cypress\reports && mkdir cypress\reports && mkdir cypress\reports\mochareports

The system cannot find the file specified.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! Cypress_Mocha@1.0.0 clean:reports: `rmdir .\cypress\reports && mkdir cypress\reports && mkdir cypress\reports\mochareports`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the Cypress_Mocha@1.0.0 clean:reports script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\aharo\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-31T16_54_14_427Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! Cypress_Mocha@1.0.0 pretest: `npm run clean:reports`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the Cypress_Mocha@1.0.0 pretest script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\aharo\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-31T16_54_14_464Z-debug.log
```

Is it possible if someone can help me a little bit more to understand what I have to do differently?

If I take a look at the logs through CMD, this is what I have:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok                                                                                     1 verbose cli [                                                                                                         1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',                                                                  1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\aharo\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',                          1 verbose cli   'run',                                                                                                  1 verbose cli   'test'                                                                                                  1 verbose cli ]                                                                                                         2 info using npm@6.14.10                                                                                                3 info using node@v15.5.0                                                                                               4 verbose run-script [ 'pretest', 'test', 'posttest' ]                                                                  5 info lifecycle Cypress_Mocha@1.0.0~pretest: Cypress_Mocha@1.0.0                                                       6 verbose lifecycle Cypress_Mocha@1.0.0~pretest: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true                                          7 verbose lifecycle Cypress_Mocha@1.0.0~pretest: PATH: C:\Users\aharo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\aharo\Desktop\Automation\Cypress_Mocha\node_modules\.bin;C:\Python39\Scripts\;C:\Python39\;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\aharo\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\aharo\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\aharo\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\aharo\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin                                                8 verbose lifecycle Cypress_Mocha@1.0.0~pretest: CWD: C:\Users\aharo\Desktop\Automation\Cypress_Mocha                   9 silly lifecycle Cypress_Mocha@1.0.0~pretest: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'npm run clean:reports' ]                            10 silly lifecycle Cypress_Mocha@1.0.0~pretest: Returned: code: 2  signal: null                                         11 info lifecycle Cypress_Mocha@1.0.0~pretest: Failed to exec pretest script                                            12 verbose stack Error: Cypress_Mocha@1.0.0 pretest: `npm run clean:reports`                                            12 verbose stack Exit status 2                                                                                          12 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\aharo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)                                                                                               12 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (node:events:376:20)                                                          12 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\aharo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)                                                                                            12 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:376:20)                                                          12 verbose stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1063:16)                                                12 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:295:5)                         13 verbose pkgid Cypress_Mocha@1.0.0                                                                                    14 verbose cwd C:\Users\aharo\Desktop\Automation\Cypress_Mocha                                                          15 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18363                                                                                        16 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\aharo\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "test"                                                                                                17 verbose node v15.5.0                                                                                                 18 verbose npm  v6.14.10                                                                                                19 error code ELIFECYCLE                                                                                                20 error errno 2                                                                                                        21 error Cypress_Mocha@1.0.0 pretest: `npm run clean:reports`                                                           21 error Exit status 2                                                                                                  22 error Failed at the Cypress_Mocha@1.0.0 pretest script.                                                              22 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
                  23 verbose exit [ 2, true ]
```

Comment: What does it tell you in the `%AppData%\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-31T*Z-debug.log` files?

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: You could do it in whichever manner you want. For instance, open up a Command Prompt window, and enter, `Type "%AppData%\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-31T*Z-debug.log"`, to type all of them to the screen at once!

Comment: ok, let me do it

Comment: 17 verbose node v15.5.0
18 verbose npm  v6.14.10
19 error code ELIFECYCLE
20 error errno 2
21 error Cypress_Mocha@1.0.0 pretest: `npm run clean:reports`
21 error Exit status 2
22 error Failed at the Cypress_Mocha@1.0.0 pretest script.
22 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
23 verbose exit [ 2, true ]

Comment: I found the issue, we just have to change "clean:reports": "del /f cypress\\reports && mkdir cypress\\reports && mkdir cypress\\reports\\mochareports" & run it through CMD instead of powershell..

Comment: You do not  need to `mkdir` both directories, when you create `cypress\reports\mochareports`, it will by default also create `cypress\reports`.